# singleton and new operator - thread safety

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that a Scott Meyers Singleton is thread-safe for C++11 and above. Is the following code also thread-safe (for C++11 and above)?

```
class T
{
    static T* obj;
public:
    T& GetInstance()
    {
        if (!obj)
        {
            obj = new T();
        }
        return *obj;
    }
};
T* T::obj=nullptr;
```

Comment: Note that singleton is usually considered a bad pattern. I never faced a place when it is actually worth (even in deep close-to-metal embedded code)

Comment: The Meyers singleton relies on the thread-safe initialization of static objects.

Comment: Why do it this way instead of the thread safe Scott Meyers Singleton way?

Comment: @AdrianMaire Singletons are definitely bad design, and I agree for 99.9% of the cases that it isn't worth it. However I have found exactly 1 (admittedly stupid) case where singletons are a useful pattern: to wrap a 3rd-party library's singleton into a required interface. Basically, the benefit of singletons are *recursive*. It's not a good justification -- it's just a realistic case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this code is not thread safe.  Two or more different threads could all call `GetInstance` at the same time and since `obj` has no synchronization (mutex, atomic variable) guarding it, then you have a data race.  Having a data race means your code has undefined behavior which is not safe.

Answer (score 3):

It is *not* thread-safe:

Two threads calling `GetInstance` at the same time could both enter the `if` block and allocate twice.

The returned object could also mismatch.